# GridLookUpEdit and Multi-part Keys

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I realize that the DevExpress GridLookUpEdit editor was not designed to work with data that has multi-part keys.  However, I am trying to workaround this limitation anyway.

The data for my GridLookUpEdit is Product-Purity with two columns "PRODUCT_ID" and "PURITY_ID".  I have this code to set the purity of the underlying grid when the user selects the product-purity row in the GridLookupEdit:

```
    void lookUpEditProductPurities_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the purity from the product selected and update the purity column of the grid.
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.GridLookUpEdit editor = (sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.GridLookUpEdit);
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view = editor.Properties.View as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView;
        object val = view.GetRowCellValue(view.FocusedRowHandle, "PURITY_ID");
        if (editor.Parent is GridControl)
        {
            GridControl ParentGridControl = (editor.Parent as GridControl);
            GridView ParentGridView = (ParentGridControl.MainView as GridView);
            DataRow CurrentDataRow = ParentGridView.GetDataRow(ParentGridView.FocusedRowHandle);
            CurrentDataRow["PRODUCT_PURITY_ID"] = val;
        }
    }
```

This works fine when I use it from a master grid, with one small problem.  When an existing row refers to a purity that is not the first purity for a product, popping the grid will make it appear as though the first purity is selected.  This is not a big deal as far as I am concerned.

However: the big problem I am having is when I use this GridLookUpEdit in a detail row of a master-detail grid.  The call: editor.Parent is returning the grid control for the master and ParentGridControl.MainView is returning the GridView for the master.

How do I get at the gridView that the GridLookUpEdit is an editor for - the child gridView??

tia -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task (getting a detail view) can be implemented using the approach shown in the [What can cause the properties, methods, and events of a detail grid view to fail?](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3082) article - use the 
[GridView.GetDetailView](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetDetailViewtopic.aspx) method.
Please also review the following article:
[Navigating Through Master and Detail Rows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument740)

Comment: The answer was right on the first link you provided!  Instead of ParentGridControl.MainView - which gives the master gridView - I used ParentGridControl.FocusedView to get the current child gridView.  Works great.  Thanks.